# for loop with array for background colors

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events

This code takes the background color from an array of divs and colors another div with it. My problem is that I can put any value from 0-2 (0-2 being the array value of the original div) in `task1[i].style.background` but when I put `i` so that the loop gives me the value specific to the one moused over it brakes.  I cannot use JQuery, JavaScript only.

EDIT: I expect `task1[i].style.background` to be equal to the background color of the specific div it hovered over from the loop running through the array.

```
var task1 = document.querySelectorAll('.t1_colors');
var task1background = document.querySelector('#task1');

var white = function() {
task1background.style.background = 'white';
}

for (var i = 0; i < task1.length; ++i) {
task1[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    colorize();
});
}

//Something wrong with i
var colorize = function() {
task1background.style.background = task1[i].style.background;
}

for (var i = 0; i < task1.length; ++i) {
task1[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        white();
});
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: And just FYI, you're missing a semi-colon for your function call after the "task1background.style.background = 'white';" statement

Comment: @RizJa in js semi-colons are not required if you do not continue your code on the same line.

Comment: @Cheery: there are cases when they are *required* (unless you restructure your code)

Comment: @zerkms That was not the case )

Comment: @Cheery: not sure I understand you. My point was that "if you do not continue your code on the same line" is terribly inaccurate

Comment: @zerkms I just told, that the problem is not in absent semi-colon here. Depending on situation, it is possible to omit it.

Comment: I'm not seeing the missing semicolon...

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the value of `i` to be when you use it in `colorize`?

```
task1background.style.background = task1[i].style.background;
```

When `colorize` executes inside `mouseover` event listener, all loops have already terminated because `i` value reached `task1.length`.

You have to capture the current `i` value.

Change it to

```
for (var i = 0; i < task1.length; ++i) {
  task1[i].addEventListener('mouseover', (function (index) {
    return function() { colorize(index); };
  })(i));
}
```

and

```
var colorize = function(index) {
  task1background.style.background = task1[index].style.background;
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your question. Thank you for your response.

Comment: You expect wrong. Read the sentence of my answer starting with "When `colorize` executes ...".